# Nginx proxy to tomcat7 webapp secured with shiro

Tags: nginx, proxy, tomcat7

So I have a Java (Spring 4 + Shiro) web app running in Tomcat7 on dedicated server. 
I'm trying to configure Nginx so that my application would be reachable by simply going to www.example.com instead of www.example.com/webappname.

With this configuration:

```
server {
   server_name www.example.com example.com;

   location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
   }

}
```

All works well when i go t www.example.com/webappname. I can log in and everything works smoothly.

When I change to:

```
server {
       server_name www.example.com example.com;

       location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/mywebappname/;
         proxy_redirect http://localhost:8080/mywebappname/ /;
       }        
    }
```

I can access the application simply through www.example.com, shiro automatically `redirects to www.example.com/login;jsessionid=CE70703C4BFBF7A258E4926324D5ECD2`
I can log in, but then clicking any link inside results in ending up on the login page again as if the cookies are not there or something. I can't figure this one out. Any advice?